# ¿Cómo cambiar los estados con Socket.IO en ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, socket, socket.io

Requiero cambiar los estados de la aplicación mediante de Socket.IO ya que cada 5 minutos se debe cambiar el background de la interfaz en ReactJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues puedes hacer varias cosas, si quieres que sea cada 5 minutos, se me ocurre un `setInterval` que lance desde el servidor un evento X `socket.emit('change-background'` al que tu cliente escucha (socket.on(...)) y puedas cambiar el estado `setState(...)`.

Espero que lo entiendas y lo puedas desarrollar, si tienes dudas comenta y amplio la respuesta, lo que no quiero es dártelo todo hecho ya que no aportas nada del código que llevas avanzado.

UPDATE:

Ejecuta este código en el arranque de tu aplicación, por ejemplo.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL);

export default socket;
```

Y después en cualquier parte donde quieras hacer uso de los eventos, simplemenente importa este fichero y setea los eventos que necesites, te pongo un ejemplo:

Si quieres escuchar el evento un evento concreto...

```
  socket.on(chat._id, (message, sender) => {
    setMessages([...messages, { user: sender, text: message }]);
  });
```

Si quieres enviar un mensaje al servidor...

```
socket.emit('new-message', chat, message, local);
```

Saludos!

Comment: Ok. Anexo un snippet. El problema lo presento que no se como enviar un evento al servidor.  https://gist.github.com/LeonardJAvi/a4d0b01314044f97bc0431b0d3b5b545

Comment: En primer lugar tendría que saber si ya tienes conectado el cliente con el servidor socket. Entiendo que tienes un servidor corriendo socket.io escuchando, correcto?

Comment: Correcto! Tengo un servidor Socket.IO corriendo. Anexo link del repositorio: https://bit.ly/2Op1KlE

Comment: Para enviar eventos al servidor, tienes que instalar el cliente de socket.io en el front, realizar la conexión y emitir eventos, en cuanto pueda te paso un ejemplo

Comment: Ah ok, perfecto! Se lo agradeceria.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, espero que te sirva.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Mil gracias.